# "The request of a dependency is an expression" webpack error from npm package

Tags: mongodb, webpack

I tried to install mongodb with npm and there's a chain of other required packages that it installed along with it, one of them being the require_optional package. When I run my program I get this error from webpack:

```
WARNING in ./~/require_optional/index.js
Critical dependencies:
63:18-42 the request of a dependency is an expression
71:20-44 the request of a dependency is an expression
78:35-67 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/require_optional/index.js 63:18-42 71:20-44 78:35-67
```

Here is the code that brings up the error:

```
var require_optional = function(name, options) {
//unrelated code
try {
    // Validate if it's possible to read the module
    moduleEntry = require(moduleEntryFile);                      // line 63
  } catch(err) {
    // Attempt to resolve in top level package
    try {
      // Get the module entry file
      moduleEntryFile = resolveFrom(process.cwd(), name);
      if(moduleEntryFile == null) return undefined;
      // Attempt to resolve the module
      moduleEntry = require(moduleEntryFile);                   // line 71
    } catch(err) {
      if(err.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') return undefined;
    }
  }

  // Resolve the location of the module's package.json file
  var location = find_package_json(require.resolve(moduleEntryFile));       // line 78

//unrelated code
```

I don't really know what to do in this situation given that I didn't write the code and don't know how to re-write the code (if I should?) so that it doesn't break another part of the require_optional package, or another package.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: [require_optional](https://github.com/christkv/require_optional) is published as a seperate module ( although it's only published dependant is the mongodb core driver ). Clearly the methods employed are not compatible with what `webpack` is trying to do. So your choices seem to be 1. Forget webpack since this is not going to work unaltered. 2. Raise an issue on the require_optional project 3. Fork and work out your own logic that would be compatible. Noting that 2 and 3 are somewhat related in that if you really want a solution then you best do both.

Comment: If of course this is all a bit "out of your wheelhouse", then the path of least resistance would be option 1.